# Power BI DAX to Find/Calculate Specific Value within String

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to find a specific value within a string of text and calculate the number of rows that have that value. However, each DAX formula that I have written, returns 1.

Example String
AB; AB-Assessment; MyComponent; Onboarding; ID:1234; Triaged

Example DAX Formulas:

```
ComponentTeam_MyComponent = 
  CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(
       FILTER('MyTable', 
       FIND("MyComponent", 'MyTable'[Tags],,0)>0)))

ComponentTeam_MyComponent = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('MyTable'),
            SEARCH("MyComponent", 'MyTable'[Tags],,0)>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [CONTAINSSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax)?

```
ComponentTeam_MyComponent =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'MyTable',
        CONTAINSSTRING ( 'MyTable'[Tags], "MyComponent" )
    )
)
```